# How to round while using Case and Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Query where I'm pulling employee time card information.  It pulls the Name, Payroll ID, Locaiton, regular hours and overtime hours.  However, I can't figure out how to round the regular and overtime hours correctly using case and Sum.  Below is my code, that is NOT rounding.

```
SELECT        Employee_Tb.First_Name + ' ' + Employee_Tb.Last_Name AS Name, Employee_Tb.Home_Store_Id, Employee_Tb.Payroll_Id, 
                         CASE WHEN SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked) > 40.0 THEN 40.0 ELSE Round(SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked), 2) END AS RegHours, 
                         CASE WHEN SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked) > 40.0 THEN Round(SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked), 2) - 40.0 ELSE 0.0 END AS OTHours
FROM            Employee_Tb INNER JOIN
                         Payroll_Hours_Tb ON Employee_Tb.Employee_Id = Payroll_Hours_Tb.Employee_Id
WHERE        (Payroll_Hours_Tb.Work_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
GROUP BY Employee_Tb.Payroll_Id, Employee_Tb.First_Name, Employee_Tb.Last_Name, Employee_Tb.Home_Store_Id
ORDER BY Employee_Tb.Home_Store_Id
```

An example of a result is:  Regular hours "21.91999999"
It Should be: "21.92"

Comment: Cast the result to `decimal(10, 2)` or whatever format you like.

Comment: This was perfect.  I'll accept it as an answer if you wanted to post it.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
convert(int,Round(SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked), 0))
```

This will get rid of the extra integers